# Comparing JSON objects in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, json

how do you read and compare JSON data in NodeJS?

```
{
  "currentcount": 150,
  "hasStorm": false,
  "players": [
    {
      "world": "earth",
      "armor": 0,
      "name": "ceduuu",
      "x": 5400.0,
      "y": 115.0,
      "health": 0,
      "z": -11309.0,
      "sort": 1,
      "type": "player",
      "account": "ceduuu"
    },
    {
      "world": "-some-other-bogus-world-",
      "armor": 0,
      "name": "Egga_",
      "x": 0.0,
      "y": 64.0,
      "health": 0,
      "z": 0.0,
      "sort": 1,
      "type": "player",
      "account": "Egga_"
    },
```

There are 150 of individual data, and I would like to temporarily store X, Z and account in a variable for me to do my comparing.
However how exactly would I check the first player's data and how would I check the seconds player data?

Comment: How is this JSON stored? Is it a file on disk? Did you read node.js docs?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you would like to compare the objects to, but here is some code to get you started.

```
const comparePlayers = (players) => {
  // iterates over each object
  players.forEach(player => {
    // destructure object
    const { x, z, account } = player;

    // your compare players logic

  });
};

comparePlayers(jsonData.players);
```